# insert one query into multiple table in function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store separate field in table 1 to table 2 i use this function but query error
**function.php**

```
function insert_content($judul_content,$kode_user,$penulis,$content,$keyword,$deskripsi){
        $koneksi = connection();
        $data = mysql_query("insert into content (judul_content,kode_user,tanggal,penulis,content,keyword,deskripsi) values ('$judul_content','$kode_user',now(),'$penulis','$content','$keyword','$deskripsi'); insert into content_user (judul_content,nama_lengkap) values ('$judul_content','$penulis');") or die ("query error");
        destroy_connection($koneksi);
        return $data;
    }
```

when i insert in table content, judul_content and penulis only store in to table content_user automatically

**table content**

```
kode_content | judul_content | kode_user | deskripsi | penulis
  1          |   abcd        |   3       |   tes     |  user1
```

**table content_user**

```
judul_content  |  penulis
   abcd        |   user1
```

Thanks

Comment: you have two queries inside of your `mysql_query` call.  You need to break that up into two separate calls.  Also you should use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `mysql_query` function you can execute only one sql statement. So you have to do 2 calls.
i.e:

```
mysql_query("insert into content (judul_content,kode_user,tanggal,penulis,content,keyword,deskripsi) values ('$judul_content','$kode_user',now(),'$penulis','$content','$keyword','$deskripsi')") or die ("query error");
mysql_query("insert into content_user (judul_content,nama_lengkap) values ('$judul_content','$penulis');") or die ("query error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) and the problem is that mysql_query only handles one query at a time.

You can switch to **mysqli** and use [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

mysql_* functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Also mysql* functions are depreciated. You should use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

In MySQLi you can use [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Using `mysql_query`, you should split the statements in to two:

```
mysql_query("insert into content (judul_content,kode_user,tanggal,penulis,content,keyword,deskripsi) values ('$judul_content','$kode_user',now(),'$penulis','$content','$keyword','$deskripsi')") or die ("query error");
mysql_query("insert into content_user (judul_content,nama_lengkap) values ('$judul_content','$penulis');") or die ("query error");
```

Comment: yes it work same with above ... thanks for your reply